# trying to turn a string of words from a file into an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, exception

Sorry if this is a really obvious question but I have tried so much code at this point and nothing seems to be working.  I have a file which I have scanned in and then saved in a String.  I now need the words in the string to be converted into an array, which later I will be splitting up to put in a JTextfield.  This is the code I have so far and currently im getting a 'No such element exception when I try to print the contents of  the array.
also apologies for all the commented out code, but It might show what I have tried, what is working/not working for me.

also I previously scanned it in and immediately turned it into an ArrayList but this isnt suitable for the rest of the project so I had to change it to string instead.

```
public void classesIn() {

    try {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        // input.useDelimiter("[,\\s]");

        String theTimetable = null;

        while ((theTimetable = input.next()) != null) {
            // System.out.println(theTimetable);

            dasTimetable = theTimetable;
            // System.out.println(dasTimetable);

        }

        // System.out.println(theTimetable[2]);
        // theTimetable.add(input.next());

        input.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stringtoArray(String dt, String[] tt) {

    tt = timeTables;

    // String[]timeTables ;

    dt = dasTimetable;

    timeTables = dasTimetable.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < timeTables.length; i++) {
        timeTables[i] = timeTables[i].replaceAll("^\\w]", "");
        System.out.println(timeTable[i]);

        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(timeTables));
        // System.out.println(words);
        // System.out.println(dasTimetable);

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to split the string into words or characters?

Comment: How are these methods related? Can you show us the line where the error is occuring?

Comment: BTW `input.next()` breaks the input into words already.

Comment: You should supply a small example that runs, you have many undefined variables in your displayed code which would cause numerous errors.  Improving the readability of your code will help others know what's going on

Answer (score 1):

If want to convert words in a file to an array, then the simplest approach is to add the words to a List then convert list to an array when done.

Here's snippet to convert file to array of words:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    input.useDelimiter("[,\\s]");
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String s = input.next();
        if (!s.isEmpty()) {
            //System.out.println(s);
            words.add(s);
        }
    }
    input.close();
    // now convert list to an array     
    String[] table = words.toArray(new String[words.size()]);
```

If want just the words may want to add other punctuation characters to the delimiter pattern; e.g. `[,;\\s\\.]` otherwise will have words that include those characters.

If rather want a single string with the concatenated tokenized words then use StringBuilder rather than an ArrayList.

```
StringBuilder sb = StringBuilder();
while (input.hasNext()) {
        String s = input.next();
        if (!s.isEmpty()) {
            if (sb.length() != 0) sb.append(' ');
            sb.append(s);
        }
}
// create concatenated string with all words separated by whitespace
String words = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
while ((theTimetable = input.next()) !=null) {
    //System.out.println(theTimetable);

    dasTimetable = theTimetable;
    //System.out.println(dasTimetable);

}
```

You are overwriting your string with the contents of input.next(). After that loop terminates, you will only have the list value of input.next() held in dasTimetable.

I recommend that you append the value from each iteration to an ArrayList and then concatenate all of its contents together into a String.